# StackOverflowException using GSON in Java

Tags: java, gson, stack-overflow

I am using GSON to convert my custom objects into JSON formatted .txt files. My problem is that when I run all of the above code I get a StackOverflowException only because line 2 and line 4 are both present. If I comment out one of them, the other line works and I get the correct result. My question is how can fix my code to allow both to work? Or is it that my computer needs more RAM Memory as I currently have 4GB? Thanks!

Additional Points -the performSpatialPoolingOnRegion() method is not recursive. All it does is change the states of custom objects in LGNRegion.

You can view the implementation of SpatialPooler.java here: https://github.com/quinnliu/WalnutiQ/blob/master/WalnutiQ/src/model/MARK_II/SpatialPooler.java

```
SpatialPooler spatialPooler = new SpatialPooler(LGNRegion);

Set<ColumnPosition> LGNNeuronActivity = spatialPooler // line 2
.performSpatialPoolingOnRegion();

assertEquals(11, LGNNeuronActivity.size()); // <= this let's me know that the 
// method performSpatialPoolingOnRegion on the line above is working correctly.


String regionObject = this.gson.toJson(LGNRegion); // line 4
JsonFileInputOutput.saveObjectToTextFile(regionObject,
"./tests/model/util/test_saveRegionObject.txt");
```

Comment: The code of `SpatialPooler` is needed here.

Comment: possible duplicate of [StackOverflowException in Java using GSON](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17358626/stackoverflowexception-in-java-using-gson)

Comment: Most likely LGNRegion has a circular reference. An instance variable that points to itself or a child and parent that point at each other. I'd guess it only shows up after performSpatialPoolingOnRegion() sets some of those references.